# Hi, i am trying to accept just numbers in the input of my program but i got wrong message

Tags: java

I want to Accept just 0,1 or 2 in input in this program, otherwise to get invaild input, can anybody help With it please ?
I have tried to change the String to double but doesnt work neither

```
Scanner da = new Scanner(System.in);
String name;                          
int big=0;                         
int[] marks = new int[5];              
String getData()
{
    int total=0;                                
    String one="one";                           
    System.out.println("");
    name = da.nextLine();
    System.out.println("");
    big=da.nextInt();
    for(int b=0;b<5;b++)

        System.out.println("+(b+1));
        marks[b]=da.nextInt();
        if(b==4) da.nextLine();  
    if(total>big)  {
        big = total;                      
        return name;                                    
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `default` case in your `switch` statement, to handle inputs that don't match any of the "valid" `case`s?

Comment: Or are you more concerned with what happens if user tries to type something that's not a number at all (like if my choice is Stein and I type "Stein" instead of "1')?  Because that would cause a rather nasty runtime error.

Comment: @Roger According to the [question revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58040202/revisions), it looks like that you destroyed your own question. Now the accepted answer does not mean anything. Can you restore the original question ? In its current state, it's very unlikely it will benefit to someone.

Comment: @GhostCat....I have restored the original now, can you leave me alone ????????????????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply loop through input until a given option has been choosen and then continue with your game.

```
while(true){
  System.out.println(" Sciccors (0), Stone(1) or Paper(2)? ");
  scanner= scan.nextLine();
  if( scanner.equals("0") || scanner.equals("1") || scanner.equals("2"))
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is input validation, while the user has not entered an integer value ask the user to re enter. I have written a example for you :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!sc.hasNextInt()){
            System.out.println("please enter again");
            sc.next();
        }
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

you can implement a separate method like this for input validation in this case.

```
public int getInputInt(Scanner sc, int max, int min) {
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                int val = sc.nextInt();
                if (val >= min && val <= max) { 
                    return val;
                }
            } else {
                sc.next();
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```